# My code crash with the following message "Thread 1:: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x8)"

Tags: c++11, vector

Im new on c++ and recently, found myself trying to understand why the code above, compile and run, but suddenly after enter the first grade crash, I figgure out that the problem was when i try to use"Grade[i] = GradeStudent " instead the "push_back" function to store the grades, but i don't understand the reason why and i really want to know  isn't work that way.
I will really appreciate any help. Sorry, if i don't write properly my question, it is the first time i make a question using stakoverflow

pd:( I wrote the preproccesor tagss: #include iostream, vector and iomanip from the standard library). Thank you

```
int main() {
    std::vector<double> Grade;
    int i = 0;
    double GradeStudent = 0.0;

    std::cout << "introduce the vector valúes.\n";
    std::cout << "To end introduce -1.\n";

    //Add grades
    while(true){
        std::cout << "Grade[" << i++ <<"] = ";
        std::cin >> GradeStudent;

        if(GradeStudent == -1){
            break;
        }

        // Grade.push_back(GradeStudent);
        Grade[i] = GradeStudent;//-->if i use that,instead the "push_back" the code crash

    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Grade[i]` crashes because the `Grade` vector is empty, so there's no element at index `i`.

`push_back` on the other hand adds the given element to the vector.